# Readable "always false" evaluation in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean

In my SQL server query I want to always get 0 results. I only want to get the metadata.

How to write an always false evaluation in TSql? Is there a built-in function, or a recommended way of doing so?

Currently I use `WHERE 1 = 0`, but I'm looking for something like `WHERE 'false'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can use `where 1 = 0` for this purpose, I think `top 0` is more common:

```
select top 0 . . . 
. . .
```

This also prevents an "accident" in the `where` clause.  If you change this:

```
where condition x or condition y
```

to:

```
where 1 = 0 and condition x or condition y
```

The parentheses are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at SET FMTONLY ON.
If you set that and run your query only the metadata is returned

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SET FMTONLY ON;
GO
SELECT * 
FROM HumanResources.Employee;
GO
SET FMTONLY OFF;
GO
```

Comment: A very clean solution, thanks a lot! In my specific case I sadly *have to* use a where clause - but it is good to know, that the `FMTONLY` keyword exists!

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the DBMS, one or more of the following will work:

```
SELECT NULL LIMIT 0 (standard SQL syntax, e.g. PostgreSQL and MySQL) / SELECT TOP 0 1 (MS SQL Server syntax)
SELECT NULL WHERE FALSE (DBMS with a boolean type, e.g. PostgreSQL) SELECT NULL WHERE 1=0 (most DBMSes)
```

For Oracle, these will need to be of the form SELECT NULL FROM DUAL, I believe, as you can't have SELECT without a FROM clause of some sort; not sure which versions of the LIMIT / TOP and WHERE it will accept.

A more elaborate option is to create a (temporary) table and not insert any rows into it, which can give you any number of columns, which will have types associated even though they contain no values:

```
-- PostgreSQL
CREATE TEMP TABLE dummy ( a Int, b VarChar(42) );
SELECT * FROM dummy;

-- MS SQL Server
CREATE TABLE #DUMMY ( a Int, b VarChar(42) );
SELECT * FROM #DUMMY;
In PostgreSQL, you can even create a table with no columns, allowing you to have a result set with zero rows and zero columns:

CREATE TEMP TABLE empty ();
SELECT * FROM empty;
Another possibility is if the DBMS has set-returning functions, they may be able to return an empty set. For instance, again in PostgreSQL as it's what I know best, you can give an invalid range to generate_series():

SELECT * FROM generate_series(0,-1);
```

Tip: Before you post a question, GOOGLE.

Comment: I want to get 0 rows, but still *all* columns of the table. As mentioned my dbms os SQL Server. I googled before posting this question.

Comment: Then select * where false

Comment: Use 2 different queries then? 1 for the false, and 1 for grabbing all the columns regardless.